# Drawback of using multiple conditions in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server

As we all know that the **where** clause of a sql query executes before **select** clause. And we put some conditions in where clause to filter out the result according to our requirement.

While writing some queries I encountered a question in my mind that, is/are there any drawback(s) of using multiple conditions in the where clause and in what order they are applied to filter the result from the selected table.

For example: we have a table

```
    Building(name,height,owner,builder_name,age)
```

and we have a query:

```
    select * from Building
    where height between X and Y and age between A and B
```

Now, how this query will execute. And what about the order of the conditions i.e.

**X<=height<=Y and A<=age<=B**

Will it be something like, first the whole record will be searched for the  height within the given range and then same thing will be done for age well. ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Database server has multiple options to solve that query. It will choose the option the server "thinks" is faster.

The options I see are:

- Scan the whole table and filter out rows that don't satisfy the `where` clause
- Seek a `height` range on an index on `height` column, then filter out rows using `age between A and B` predicate.
- Seek an `age` range on an index on `age` column, then filter out rows using `height between X and Y` predicate
- Seek both indexes, then perform an index intersection

The database server not always use an index that might be applicable, it considers some things before using it, such as:

- The index selectivity.
- The index coverage.

High selectivity indexes are more likely to be used.
Covering indexes are likely used.

Comment: @Lopez, So U are saying that instead of having a combined index i.e (height,age) one should have separate index for both columns height and age ??.... 

Now exactly the index intersection will work in this scenario ??... 

And plz give me some more info about selectivity and coverage, bcz these are new things for me as a fresher.

Answer (score 1):

The query planner will try to find the optimal way to search the table and test the `WHERE` clause. It will start by trying to use an index if possible, which will narrow down the rows that it needs to search. If there are multiple potential indexes, it will try to use the one that it estimates will narrow it down best.

Then it will scan all these rows, and test each of them against all of the remaining conditions. It should never need to make multiple passes over the entire table.

If you want to see how a particular query will be executed, use the `EXPLAIN` command.

Comment: Sir.. when we talk about searching, indexing plays an important role in that. Now my question is what if I put a combined index on (height,age); will it help in searching ?? plz suggest some other technique which can improve the search result of similar kind of query as I mentioned in question. FYI, I am considering the table with billions of record.

Comment: It might! Problem is you have 2 ranges than overlap. An index on height might be better than an index on age for the particular execution of that query, but maybe not the next one. But with a covering index there will be ranges (possibly many) within the first item that do not match the 2nd hence the 2nd part of the index is of limited use. MySQL cannot just grab a continuous range of records from the index.

Comment: @Kickstart, As per my knowledge, indexing helps us to search in O(logn).   right ??.. do you mean indexing is useful only when we are looking for a particular value not for a range of values ?? So, what else you suggest to improve the searching result ???

Plz don't mind if some of the questions seems silly, bcz as an intern lots of things are new for me and lots of question get popped up in my mind. :)

Comment: On a small range it it very useful. Like a phone book, if you know the name is between smith and smythe then you can just grab that range quickly. However if the range is large then the benefits decrease. With 2 independent ranges (for example the surname is in the range Adam to Eve, and the first name in the range John to Peter) the db cannot just grab a range based on the index, rather it has to grab lots of small ranges which may not be efficient (ie, the db might decide that just scanning the whole table is more efficient).